# Converting a stdClass intro an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

```
stdClass Object
(
    [CountyId] => 3
    [Name] => Alba
    [Abbreviation] => AB
)
stdClass Object
(
    [CountyId] => 4
    [Name] => Arad
    [Abbreviation] => AR
)
stdClass Object
(
    [CountyId] => 5
    [Name] => Arges
    [Abbreviation] => AG
)
```

I want to convert this collection of stdClass Object into an array that contains only the CountyId, such as

`[CountyId[0] => 3, CountyId[1] => 4, CountyId[2] => 5,...].`

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: The referred answer is not very helpful.

Comment: why closed? he need something like: [CountyId[0] => 3, CountyId[0] => 4, CountyId[0] => 5,...]

Comment: Do you have an array of objects? That you want to convert into ['CountyId' => [3], 'CountyId' => [4], 'CountyId' => [5], ...]?

Comment: you cant achive this with same index for all `CountryID`

Comment: Exactly. It's not clear to me what the output should be.

Comment: Do you mean to generate a map (e.g. collection index to county ids): `array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 4, 2 => 5... )`?

Comment: Is your original object collection an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = (array)$stdClassObject;    // type casting
```

**Update:**

```
// convert your object into array using type casting
$array = (array) $stdClassObject;

// use array_column for specific index
$CountyIdArr = array_column($array, 'CountyId');

// note that, you can not use same index name for all values, you need to use as
$CountyIdArr['CountryID'] = $CountyIdArr;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($CountyIdArr);
```

Comment: i am updating your answer.

Comment: I don't think array_column() works when the post is an object. Convert the posts to arrays first with array_map() or so?

Comment: OP already convert object into array, so i didnt use. @TorbjörnStabo

Comment: @devpro I think the array_column is what the OP is really after.  This line is confusing and unnecessary: `$CountyIdArr['CountryID'] = $CountyIdArr;`

Comment: @Progrock: comments tell everything bro.

Comment: @devpro,  not helpful.   I do try to read before commenting.  This answer is a little premature as the question isn't entirely clear.